# Multiple T-Tests Over Time Series Data

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, t-test

I have 2 groups, observed for 11 months.

I have observed means for each month, for each group.

Running 11 t-tests, I find that 4 of the 11 months have a significant difference in their means (at an alpha of 0.05)

My question is, how can I calculate the probability that these 4 differences were just by chance?

Comment: You flipped 11 biased coins, with probability of heads 0.05 or less, and you observed 4 heads? This is an intro to probability question. In R I would `pbinom(3, size=11, prob=0.05, lower.tail=FALSE)`

Comment: Yes, I thought this may just be a case of applying the binomial distribution. I suppose if I wanted to get the probability of up to 4 "heads", I'd need to add up the values of choosing 4, 3, 2, and 1, within the binomial distribution.

Comment: I don't agree that a binomial test would be appropriate here. You say that the subjects within the groups may be the same between months. So your months are not independent observations (one of the assumptions of a binomial test). Also, your underlying data (the measured variable) are not binomial. I think you should test for significant differences using all your data together (thus combining all of your information about the variance), and not try to test the 'significance' of multiple 'significant differences'.

Comment: Every month there will be two groups. (There is nothing stopping a member of one group from being in another group at another time - although, I think this is unlikely. I can say that this is call center data). Each group has a mean, and in 4 of those 11 months, the means appear to be significantly different.

Comment: So if you assume that calls are independent (if you have data on caller ID, you could check that this assumption is not grossly violated), then you are left with 'group' and 'month' as explanatory factors/variables. If you have no reason to believe that there is an effect of month (which would be an assumption you would make by using the binomial test), then you can combine your data from all months and do one overall t-test. If you do think there is an effect of/trend over time, then consider an ARIMA or regression model to account for this.

Comment: It also may be worth considering your justification for splitting the data by 'month'  - is that too coarse a measure of time for any patterns you may have in your data? Why would something change more dramatically in a day from the end of one month to the beginning of the next month, than in a day in the middle of a month?

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you are testing for differences between the two groups, and that the subjects in your groups are the same each month. So you have repeated measures of the same subjects.

You could try a repeated measures ANOVA (for group*month), or a mixed effects model with subject as the random factor and month, group and month.group as your fixed effects.

However, if months that are close in time to each other are more similar in their values than months that are further apart - i.e. you have some sort of pattern over time - then you have autocorrelation in your data and you ought to account for that (otherwise you'll probably end up violating the assumptions of whatever statistical test you use). You might consider ARIMA models, or a regression model with month as a numerical or ordinal variable (rather than a categorical variable) if there is a definite pattern over time rather than seemingly random fluctuations.

You should definitely aim to use an analysis that considers all of your data together, rather than using individual t-tests.

I (or someone else!) may be able to provide a more specific answer if you provide a bit more detail about your data.

Comment: Yes, I am testing for differences between the groups. The subjects within the groups may or may not be the same.

I can't be too specific about the data, unfortunately.